# Automatic backup of .tex file with TeXShop

Tags: compiling, texshop, arara

Is there a way you can get a backup of the `.tex` automatically, for example every time you compile or make changes or after a certain amount of time you're working and so on, in TeXShop?

Is it possible to use `arara` for doing something like that?

Answer (score 2):

TeXshop uses the macOS frameworks which automatically do backups so there is no need to worry about it. See File->Revert To.